# $${HOME} or ${HOME} in Makefile?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile, environment-variables

```
$ cat Makefile 
all:
    echo VAR is ${HOME}
    echo VAR is $${HOME}
```

gives

```
$ make
echo VAR is /home/abc
VAR is /home/abc
echo VAR is ${HOME}
VAR is /home/abc
```

Why does `echo VAR is ${HOME}` syntax work in Makefile? I thought to use shell variables you have to use `$${HOME}`

Comment: It depends on whether you want the makefile to expand `${HOME}` (e.g. to use it in a text function in Make) or you want the shell to expand it, in which case you need to double the `$$` so that Make passes it through.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes and no. It is best to use `$$` to be explicit. However, [there is a special rule for environment variables](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html#SEC68):

> Variables in make can come from the environment in which make is run. Every environment variable that make sees when it starts up is transformed into a make variable with the same name and value. But an explicit assignment in the makefile, or with a command argument, overrides the environment. (If the `-e' flag is specified, then values from the environment override assignments in the makefile. See section Summary of Options. But this is not recommended practice.)

Comment: Best in which sense?

Comment: Using `$${HOME}` as a target didn't work properly for me, `$(HOME)` and `${HOME}` did

Comment: @CervEd, it is best to be explicit in order to make your work understandable to someone else you want to share it with, or to yourself if you put the makefile on the back shelf for a few years and then want to start using it again. If you are not explicit, then it may take several precious hours to figure out whether and how the variable is supplied.

Comment: @Post169 I wasn't asking why it's good to be _explicit_. I was asking why _"it is best to use `$$`"_. Ironically, the answer as it currently stands is not explicit

Comment: @CervEd, `$${HOME}` is best because it's explicitly always the environment variable `HOME`. `${HOME}` is ambiguous - it is initially the environment variable, but can be overridden (via command argument or assignment in the makefile). Thus, if you plan to never override it, you should use `$${HOME}`, because it tells readers this is never overridden. I'm unsure how to make this more clear - feel free to suggest an edit to the answer!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you want `make` to expand the variable before the recipe gets run, or whether the shell should expand it at execution time.

Here's a simple (albeit rather artificial) example where you can see it makes a difference.

```
.PHONY: demonstration
demonstration:
    HOME='where the heart is'; \
    echo Make thinks '$$HOME' is '"${HOME}"' "but it's really \"$$HOME\""
```

Because `make` expands `${HOME}` it doesn't matter that it's inside a single-quoted string. On the other hand, `$$HOME` will only be expanded by the shell when it's not inside single quotes.

In more practical terms, you probably want `make` to expand any `make` variable because it's more convenient as well as efficient and transparent. In real life, `$HOME` will probably never change at run time (unless you specifically want it to, and know what you are doing) so letting `make` expand it, rather than defer it to the shell, makes sense to me.

On the other hand, shell variables which change during the execution of a recipe obviously cannot be expanded by `make` before the recipe runs, as that would hardcode the initial value.

(Perhaps notice also the semicolon and backslash after the assignment. Out of the box, each line in a recipe runs in a separate shell instance. The backslash turns the recipe into a "single line" in the sense that both lines will be passed to the same shell, so that the assignment works. Without this, you would have one shell instance assigning a value to `HOME`, then immediately exiting, and thus losing the effect of the assignment. Then the next line would be executed by a new shell instance, which of course would again inherit `make`'s environment, including the original value of `$HOME`.)

Comment: On the other hand -- expanding variables in make instead of the shell opens room for injection attacks, since things make expands go through all the parsing steps, whereas things the shell expands have an abbreviated, safer subset of processing.