# How to expand ./ to absolute path in Makefile

Tags: python, shell, makefile

I have the following excerpted from my Makefile:

```
topDirectory := ./

# This print nothing
$(info $(topDirectory))
# and as a result, myScript.py complains that I'm missing a parameter
$(shell python myScript.py $(topDirectory))
```

How do I get `./` to expand to the absolute path it references on the command line?

Comment: What you've written here can't be true: the `info` function can't show no output for this makefile.  Unless you're using such an old version of GNU make that it doesn't support the `info` function: please include the output of `make --version` in your question.  Also please include a http://sscce.org/ so we can reproduce the results.

Answer (score 1):

[Make automatically takes in all shell environment variables and makes them make variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50751253/5889131).

This means `$PWD` is a make variable, and is the full expanded path to the current working directory. You might want to use that instead.